# How to update using fast update element in visual workflow?

Tags: visual-workflow, flow, update

I keep getting stuck when trying to fast update using visual workflow
I tend to get the you cannot update without an id error.

My scenario is as follows:
I fast lookup an object with the objective of storing it's id
However, in the assignment component, I cannot assign the ID to the id field in the sObject Variable  (which i wanted to pass to the collection)

I end up having to do a record update within a loop, and I am afraid that my flow will hit SOQL limits if alot of records involved in the operation

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

THanks